# Can we change url from https to http from iframe loaded inside base url?

Tags: facebook, mod-rewrite, iframe, ssl, https

Facebook App page will get a **SSL error** when coming from secure hypertext protocol(**https**)) Facebook account to non secure(**http**) Facebook App Page, which happens  due to lack of SSL Certificate in Facebook App hosted server. I am trying to change base url from `https`to `http` to avoid SSL error.

Is it possible to change base url from `https` to `http` from iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change base url from https to http from iframe?

Even if it is, that’s no solution to your problem – because the iframe content will be pulled over HTTPS first, if the user is browsing Facebook over HTTPS – and since you app does not support HTTPS, this will fail already. So you will not even *get* to a point where code from your app will be loaded, let alone executed, in this scenario.

You’ll have to get an SSL certificate for your app domain.